# Why am I getting "An assertion failed!" error while using pgadmin3?

Tags: ubuntu, pgadmin

I am using pgadmin3 on ubuntu 15.04 and i don't have any function called GetLongLong() and when I click on continue it terminates the pgadmin3.

[image]

Text from backtrace is as follows :

```
ASSERT INFO:
db/pgSet.cpp(356): assert "col < nCols && col >= 0" failed in GetLongLong().

BACKTRACE:
[1] wxWindowList::~wxWindowList()

[2] char* std::string::_S_construct<char*>(char*, char*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag)

[3] char* std::string::_S_construct<char*>(char*, char*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag)

[4] char* std::string::_S_construct<char*>(char*, char*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag)

[5] wxString wxString::Format<wxString>(wxFormatString const&, wxString)

[6] wxString wxString::Format<wxString>(wxFormatString const&, wxString)

[7] wxString wxString::Format<wxString>(wxFormatString const&, wxString)

[8] wxAppConsoleBase::CallEventHandler(wxEvtHandler*, wxEventFunctor&, wxEvent&) const

[9] wxEvtHandler::ProcessEventIfMatchesId(wxEventTableEntryBase const&, wxEvtHandler*, wxEvent&)

[10] wxEventHashTable::HandleEvent(wxEvent&, wxEvtHandler*)

[11] wxEvtHandler::TryHereOnly(wxEvent&)

[12] wxEvtHandler::DoTryChain(wxEvent&)

[13] wxEvtHandler::ProcessEvent(wxEvent&)

[14] wxWindowBase::TryAfter(wxEvent&)

[15] wxScrollHelperEvtHandler::ProcessEvent(wxEvent&)

[16] wxGenericTreeCtrl::DoSelectItem(wxTreeItemId const&, bool, bool)

[17] wxGenericTreeCtrl::OnMouse(wxMouseEvent&)

[18] wxAppConsoleBase::CallEventHandler(wxEvtHandler*, wxEventFunctor&, wxEvent&) const

[19] wxEvtHandler::ProcessEventIfMatchesId(wxEventTableEntryBase const&, wxEvtHandler*, wxEvent&)

[20] wxEventHashTable::HandleEvent(wxEvent&, wxEvtHandler*)

[21] wxEvtHandler::TryHereOnly(wxEvent&)

[22] wxEvtHandler::ProcessEventLocally(wxEvent&)

[23] wxEvtHandler::ProcessEvent(wxEvent&)

[24] wxScrollHelperEvtHandler::ProcessEvent(wxEvent&)

[25] wxEvtHandler::SafelyProcessEvent(wxEvent&)

[26] g_closure_invoke

[27] g_signal_emit_valist

[28] g_signal_emit

[29] gtk_propagate_event

[30] gtk_main_do_event

[31] g_main_context_dispatch

[32] g_main_loop_run

[33] gtk_main

[34] wxGUIEventLoop::DoRun()

[35] wxEventLoopBase::Run()

[36] wxAppConsoleBase::MainLoop()

[37] wxEntry(int&, wchar_t**)

[38] __libc_start_main
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to connect to a Postgres 10 server?
PgAdmin 3 doesn't support such connections.
To connect to Postgres 10 you'll have to use PgAdmin 4 instead.

I've faced that same problem trying to connect to Postgres 10 server using pgadmin3, version 1.22.2, on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. It worked with pgadmin 4, version 3.5.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No, we were using postgres 9.3 back then.